# Denying user permissions for C Drive where Windows is installed

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, storage

I have added another user profile to my PC and have removed their access to the D drive through properties > security > edit and removing other users permissions (picture below for context).

With instructions from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWxx9uz1bP8

However I'd like to know if doing this for the C drive (where Windows is installed) will this cause any potential issues?

Comment: Yes, it will cause that user account to be unusable, so why bother.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by removing the permissions?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want other users to have access to my files and installed applications, that's why I'd like to remove their permission to access the drive entirely.

Comment: By default, a user cannot access another user's files contained within their profile directory.  Only an Administrator can do that, but even if you were to revoke the permissions of a user yourself, if they are an Administrator they could grant those permissions back.

Comment: Close voters: Asking, "*Will [this] cause any potential issues?*" may sound broad, but because the answer is the same under **all** circumstances, this isn't a broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that and still have the user be able to use the computer.
Every user needs a minimum of read access to large parts of Windows itself and Full Control to certain portions of his own profile-folder which is also located on C:.
Without those rights the user can't login at all. You might just as well delete that user-account altogether and that is actually much easier to do.

In addition to that the file-access permissions to the Windows folders in C: are extremely complicated and are not a single set of settings that you can apply from the top of the disk as shown in that video.
If you try to do that on C: you will mess up your Windows installation to the point that you have to re-install it from scratch.

The instructions given in that video work, but only for drives that are used for data only. Don't try it with disks containing the Operating System.
Disks that contain installed software (other than the software installed on C:) might also cause issues. Some of the programs will malfunction or not work at all.

Comment: +1 for the "don't change the permissions on the system drive" since it will indeed cause problems.  *eriously don't attempt to change the permission on the system drive.*